# TFS 2012 API Get Field SUMMARY Object TESTCASE

Tags: tfs

SUMMARY get the field as in the TestCase object, I get the code to retrieve the Steps and Expected Results, No SUMMARY. 
Please your help.

thank you

```
         for (int i = 0; i < testPlan.TestSuites.Count; i++)
            {
                var ts = testPlan.TestSuites[i];

                ITestSuiteEntryCollection suiteentrys = ts.TestCases;

                foreach (ITestSuiteEntry item in suiteentrys)
                {

                    ITestCase tes = item.TestCase;

                    tfsTestCase testcase = new tfsTestCase();
                    testcase.Suite = testPlan.TestSuites[i].Title;
                    testcase.Nombre = tes.Title;

                    foreach (ITestAction action in tes.Actions)
                    {
                        ITestStep er = action as ITestStep;

                        testcase.NumeroPaso = er.Id;
                        testcase.Paso = er.Title;
                        testcase.ResultadoEsperado = er.ExpectedResult;
                        testcase.Descripcion = er.Summary ??? ;

                    }

                    lsttestcase.Add(testcase); 
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

the test-*step* doesn't have a summary. The test-*case* is comprised of test-steps, and it's the test-case that has the summary.

Comment: which is the object to get the SUMMARY field

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

testCase.CustomFields["Summary"];